# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Windows XP

Tags: system-installation, busybox

I'm using a USB to install Ubuntu 16.04 and when I tell it to install a screen comes up that says "BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands (initramfs)" I tried testing Ubuntu without installing, but it does the same thing. 
what should I do?

My previous question about version twelve was a mistake. sorry about the confusion

Comment: Are you saying that the busybox screen appears while running the USB-based installer? If so, then you mis-made the USB installer. Show us a link to the instructions you followed.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows  this is the link

Comment: Did you skip any steps? Modify any steps? Receive any warnings or error messages? Did you [verify the .iso file](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) that you downloaded?

Comment: What brand/model system. If old XP system, better to use lighter weight flavor of Ubuntu. Light weight flavors
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors